# Add Data Row inside Data Column

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I wanted to create row data into column data, but I was at a loss as to what to do. I want to make a data table like this for example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWvn.gif) . Can anyone help me to fix the problem?

This is my code:

```
Widget data() {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(
            sortAscending: true,
            sortColumnIndex: 0,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    "code",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                  tooltip: "study code"),
                  
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                "study",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              )),
            ],
            rows: [
              DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(Text("1")),
                  DataCell(Text("math")),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(Text("1")),
                  DataCell(Text("math")),
                ],
              ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        data()
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to tell where you have a syntax error, such as missing a closing bracket or brace when you have very deeply nested widgets all ***inline*** in your source code.

Instead it's recommended that you breakup any complex widgets into smaller separate widgets (not builder methods) - Flutter is very good at handling deep trees of widgets so there is no need to be afraid of creating lots of your own custom widget classes.

Here is a simplified version of your code that works for me in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). I would suggest starting from that and gradually adding other things such as a containing listview, margins, teststyles etc that you need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
      child: DataTable(
        sortAscending: true,
        sortColumnIndex: 0,
        columns: const [
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              "code",
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              "study",
            ),
          ),
        ],
        rows: const [
          DataRow(
            cells: [
              DataCell(Text("1")),
              DataCell(Text("math")),
            ],
          ),
          DataRow(
            cells: [
              DataCell(Text("1")),
              DataCell(Text("math")),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```